# Axios - Getting socket hang up error while running it on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, axios, containers

I am trying to get results from third party API by using Axios npm. Using nested request, first request is to get the token and another one is to get results.

Below code is working fine in my local machine but not in Docker container.

```
    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: gsecConfig.tokenUrl,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: data
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.access_token) {
                const config = {
                    headers: { Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data.access_token}` }
                };

                axios.get(gsecConfig.gsecUrl + gsecid, config)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        let supplierData = response.data;
                        res.status(200).json({
                            "data": supplierData
                        });
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        res.json({
                    "errors": error.message,
                    "name": error.name
                });
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (tokenError) {
            if (tokenError) {
                res.json({
                    "errors": tokenError.message,
                    "name": tokenError.name
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Getting error like below

```
"message": "socket hang up",
"name": "Error",
"stack": "Error: socket hang up\n    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)\n    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)",
"code": "ECONNRESET"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If your server is not Kubernetes, you can change the publish mode to host (default is ingress), the problem will be solved. [check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYCDV.png)
You can change it in docker-stack like below:

```
ports:
      - target: 3001
        published: 3001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
```

But if this is Kubernetes with node clusters, you should use the ingress mode, I'm facing this issue and still stuck here. Hope someone can help.